# Как с помощью Glide загрузить изображение в память телефона?

Tags: android, glide

Моя задача: Сохранить картинку на телефон

Попытка:

```
          Glide.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                    .load(URLIMAGE)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "error while preload image by Glide");
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .preload();
```

Вроде пытался реализовать используя документацию, но почему то этот код на телефон ничего не сохраняет. Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку

Comment: Что происходит? Что ожидаете? Мне кажется данный код просто запрелоадит картинку в дисковый кэш, и при следующем обращении покадет ее оттуда. ВОзможно что вы хотите реализовано тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/44762833/5892568

Comment: Если не принципиально, то я бы использовал picasso. Во первых он по умолчанию работает с ARGB, а во вторых в нем есть готовый метод для получения Bitmap -  "Picasso.with(this)
                        .load(path)
                        .get();"